# basic CSS not working

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple web page and I thought i had linked the html page to the css page but it doesnt seem to load. Is it because the code i want to add css to is inside a div, am i writing the code wrong in css or am i just missing something basic.

html

```
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Insert Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="whole_page">

<div class="header_small">
<img src="header.jpg" id="siteMainHeader" alt border="0"
<!-- end header -->

<div id=”navMain”>
<h2> Categories </h2>
<ul>
<li><a href=”#”> Home</a></li>
<li><a href=”#”> Visit our site </a></li>
<li><a href=”#”> About</a></li>
<li><a href=”#”> Newsletter</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- end navbar-->

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
 id.siteMainHeader img{
 width:100%;
 }

 div.navMain ul{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 margin-left:33px;
 } 

 div.navMain {
 color:#c3c3c3;
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 background:#eff3f0;
 border:thin solid #e8ece9;
 width:200px;
 padding:14px;
 } 

 div.navMain h2{
 font-family:Trebuchet MS1, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin-top:0;
 }
```

Comment: Please change <link> as follow
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

Comment: You are missing a type="text.css" from inside the link tag

Comment: That depends on where your file is located. And you should use meta before linking to stylesheet.

Comment: it doesn't matter if he has type='text/css' or not.

Comment: Is your style.css file located in the same directory as your HTML file?

Answer (score 5):

`id.siteMainHeader img` This doesn't make any sense, if you want to target an ID use # instead of `id.` Example: `#siteMainHeader`

`div.navMain`
You're basically saying:
Target a div with the class `navMain`, but in your code you have an `id` with the name `navMain`

I recommend learning selectors http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

This should work:

```
 #siteMainHeader{
 width:100%;
 }

 #navMain ul{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 margin-left:33px;
 } 

 #navMain {
 color:#c3c3c3;
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 background:#eff3f0;
 border:thin solid #e8ece9;
 width:200px;
 padding:14px;
 } 

 #navMain h2{
 font-family:Trebuchet MS1, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin-top:0;
 }
```

Comment: This answer is spot on. Here is a jsFiddle of a similar method: http://jsfiddle.net/e379Ljjw/

Comment: the css is working on the header but the css isn't working on the nav bar

Comment: @Chris It is working here, take a look at the fiddle @JClaspill posted above your comment, if you want to test if it's working you can add something silly to your css like `background-color:red;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure the "img" tag is closed with ">".
Then, in your css you can't say id.siteMainHeader if you want to recall the id you assigned in your HTML page. You have to say #siteMainHeader or div.siteMainHeader, then your css code for the img should works.
Otherwise, you don't have to say #sitemMainHeader img {}, cause your id is already refering to the img of your css. So just put #siteMainHeader {...your code...} and then it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Try a layout like this:

```
.siteMainHeader{
 width:100%;
 }

<img src="header.jpg" class="siteMainHeader" alt border="0">
```